# "This shirt is nice for me" or "It is nice for me to wear this shirt"?

Tags: word-usage

does this sentence "**This shirt is nice for me**" sound strange?

This structure "**It is Adj for somebody to do something**" is popular.

Ex: "**It is nice for me to wear this shirt**"

"**This shirt is nice for me**" or "**It is nice for me to wear this shirt**"?

**Which one is ok or both are ok?**

Comment: None of them sound particularly good. I would suggest something along the lines of "This shirt looks/feels good on me" or "I look/feel good in this shirt".

Comment: I agree with Morgan Freeman ))) "for" sounds weird, very weird.